# Saving pdf-file as blob

Tags: php, sql, pdf

I am trying to save a pdf-file as a blob into my database.
It works fine on newer files, but I have problem with some older files.
The files are all scanned images, so there isn't any text in them.
Here's some code:

```
$path=$_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"];
$name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size= $_FILES['file']['size'];
$blob = fopen($path,'r');
$blob=fread($blob,filesize($path));
$stmt = $sqlConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO file(blob,name,size) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $blob, $name, $size);
$stmt->execute();
```

I tried changing the bind_param like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('bss', $blob, $name, $size);
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `b` flag to `fopen()`: `fopen($path,'rb');`

Comment: I had that one already, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok never mind, it was about the file size XD

facepalm*